# Trade-off between explaining variance and correcting overdispersion

Tags: regression, data-transformation, linear-model, overdispersion

I am fitting linear model. I happen to be working in R, and the specific model I'm fitting is a generalized additive model using the package mgcv, but I think all that is incidental to my question.

When I evaluate the model, it is clear that my residuals are overdispersed.
[image]

I am able to correct this with a simple square-root transformation of Y.
[image]

But when I compare my original (overdispersed) model to my corrected model, I see that I have taken a substantial loss in explained variance, from ~80% to ~65%. I have two questions:

1. Is there a fundamental reason for this apparent tradeoff between correcting overdispersion and explaining variance?
2. My understanding (possibly incorrect) of issues like overdispersion is that they pertain mainly to the validity of p-values and confidence intervals, and are therefore mainly a concern in the context of hypothesis testing. I know a priori that there is a causal relationship between X and Y, and my goal is to characterize that relationship, not to prove it. So, I don't care p-values (they are vanishingly small for both models anyway). Does it, therefore, make sense to accept overdispersion for the sake of capturing more variance?

Thanks for helping me think this through.